# Reuse AdamOptimizer and avoid strange behavior / out of memory

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run 100 x 100 different short minimizations without creating 10000 sessions and optimizers.

If I create a new AdamOptimizer for each minimization, I get out of memory error. But each optimizer works. The loss nearly always decreases.

I try the following:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1)
for i in range(100):
    self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer(), feed_dict=...)
    tf.variables_initializer(optimizer.variables())
    # run 100 minimizations with the optimizer
```

But the behavior of the optimizer is very strange. The loss would decrease and increase for several times. When the loss is small, it would suddenly increases a lot, as in [Loss suddenly increases with Adam Optimizer in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221348/loss-suddenly-increases-with-adam-optimizer-in-tensorflow?rq=1)

AdamOptimizer internally tracks the number of times that it is called without using a variable: [How to initialise only optimizer variables in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533489/how-to-initialise-only-optimizer-variables-in-tensorflow?noredirect=1&lq=1)

That means `tf.global_variables_initializer()` cannot reset this count. That may cause the strange behavior.

How to reuse the AdamOptimizer?

Comment: "without creating 10000 sessions and optimizers." Is there a lot of overhead involved in this operation?  I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @Scott out of gpu memory. tensorflow won't free gpu memory until the python process ends. so creating a new session won't make it free the memory.

Comment: less strange behavior if i use: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/optimizer_v2/adam.py Won't completely eliminate it. but it makes 50% of the runs normal. seems to be one normal run followed by one abnormal run. but i am not sure. this looks semi-random.

Comment: I guess I can try to initialize the variables for twice before running the optimization.

Comment: @Scott https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19731

Comment: erh. if I create 3 optimizers in the same session, i get oom. so optimizers don't reuse the same memory. the recommended solution in that issue is to start a new subprocess. But tf takes time to connect to the gpu.

Comment: This is surprising to me.  I recall having written code in the past that uses many sessions *specifically to avoid gpu OOM errors*.  The goal was to allow me to dispose of the graph and whatever when I no longer needed the model.  Let me go poke through that...

Comment: "3 optimizers in the same session."  If you close the session to get the memory back, I think tf will reuse it.

Comment: Why not create an optimizer for each `i` but keep the session constant? This should work for both v1 and v2 `AdamOptimizer`.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev That will lead to out of gpu memory. The optimizer contains internal variables, which become part of the computation graph. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19731

Comment: also this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8057